# My newly created Quickly app gets warnings on install

Tags: package-management, quickly

I've created my very first, very simple app with Quickly (basically just followed the tutorial). But when i run the program i get warnings:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `OpenDialog' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `JottyWindow' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `RemoveDialog' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```

it doesn't hinder the app, but if somebody know how to get rid of them it would be great.

When I try to package the app with "quickly package" i get:

```
simon@simonsDeskTop:~/programing_with_quickly/jotty$ quickly package
.........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.................................................................................................................................................................................................
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
** (setup.py:9781): WARNING **: Fel vid sändning av inloggningsuppgifter: Fel vid sändning av meddelande: Operationen inte tillåten
----------------------------------
Ubuntu package has been successfully created in ../jotty_0.1_all.deb
```

Sorry about the sweedish, but it means "Error when sending account information: Error when sending message: Operation not allowed"

And when I try to install the app with the softwear center i get the following warning:

```
Lintian check results for /home/simon/programing_with_quickly/jotty_0.1_all.deb:
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/lintian line 108.
E: jotty: maintainer-address-malformed UNKNOWN <UNKNOWN>
```

And then it recommends not to install. (but the app works great when i install it!)

So, the question is, how to get rid of the warning?

Is it only because the app has not been approved by Canonical or is it something else?

Thanks!

I'm runing ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those package errors try to set some more information in the "install.py" file.

```
DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(
   name='chatbox',
   version='0.1',
   #license='GPL-3',
   #author='Your Name',
   #author_email='email@ubuntu.com',
   #description='UI for managing …',
   #long_description='Here a longer description',
   #url='https://launchpad.net/chatbox',
   cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory}
)
```

Remove those "#" characters from author, author_email, description, long_description. And fill in the information.

For those GTK warning i think there is something serious wrong with your glade design files. Try to look if you set them properly.

Answer (score 0):

For Gtk.py warnings, you can modify your /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py (line 391)

from:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, type=Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, **kwds):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```

to:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, type=Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, **kwds):
        # type is a construct-only property; if it is already set (e. g. by
        # GtkBuilder), do not try to set it again and just ignore it
        try:
            self.get_property('type')
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, **kwds)
        except TypeError:
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```